# Fortran legacy code

Tags: floating-point, fortran, svd

I have been asked to improve the code for singular value decomposition we've been using for years (it's from Numerical Recipes' last edition that was available for Fortran), but someone adapted it for a different real `kind` type. I have some questions, one concerning precision, and the others concerning floating-point comparison, but first here's some code (only relevant stuff shown):

```
  implicit real(kind=selected_real_kind(12)) (a-h,o-z)      ! not from Numerical Recipes
  parameter R12 = selected_real_kind(12), eps=tiny(1.0_R12) ! not from Numerical Recipes

  do i=1,n
    scale=0.0
    if (i.le.m) then 
      do k=i,m
        scale=scale+abs(a(k,i))
      end do
      if (scale.ne.0.0) then
```

1. `scale=0.0` should be `scale=0.0_R12`, right?
2. Would it be fine to exchange `scale.ne.0.0` for `scale.gt.0.0` (as it cannot be < 0) to avoid the explicit `.ne.`-comparison, or ought I to compare it to some epsilon instead?
3. Regarding the last point, which of the intrinsic functions `tiny` and `epsilon` is preferable for selecting the epsilon-value in the abovementioned comparison?
4. In case the value that is tested for not being equal to 0 may be both positive and negative, would `(value.gt.eps .or. value.lt.-1.0_R12*eps)` be a sensible condition?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it an option to use a dedicated optimized library like [lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/)?

Comment: How exactly would .gt.0.0 be of greater precision than .ne.0.0? I'm amazed by the number of people knowing that comparing floats can lead to false positive/negative, but magically thinking that inequalities would behave better or be immune... If you have some dumb lint rule for .eq. then it must be applied equally to .gt.

Comment: notice the implicit statement makes the *parameter* R12 *real*.

Comment: @damienfrancois I doubt it, I think the rest of the team will want to stick to what we've been using for years...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge,

1. The compiler ought to fix that for you, but it might be more reasonable to explicitly declare it as `0.0_R12` for future editors of the code. It might be more prudent to define `real(r12), parameter :: zero = 0.0_r12` as a global variable
2. Comparing to something slightly larger machine epsilon probably would be a good idea
3. I would use `epsilon` over `tiny`
4. If `value` could be positive *or* negative, it'd probably make sense to use `if(abs(value) > eps) then` rather than try comparing two values in a single if statement.

Note that Numerical Recipes is [copyrighted material](http://www.astro.umd.edu/~bjw/software/boycottnr.html), even after modifying you aren't allowed to distribute it due to this copyright. It's better to use [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) or some other GPL/BSD licensed linear algebra package, instead of that (ancient & often slow) material.

Comment: There is no reason to care about kinds for integer values like 0. I would not hesitate to omit the ".0" part altogether.

Comment: @VladimirF: agreed, and in practice I often omit the decimal in my values, but I'm really the only one *using* my codes, so I do it knowing what I mean. When you're giving your code to someone who is less than familiar with the language, it *might* come off to that person as meaning an integer. In that regards it might be safer to assume future users/editors are #$%^ing morons.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt: It's got to be said. It's useful for learning how to take an equation or two and turn it into a useful subroutine, but it's awful that the authors put such a restrictive copyright on it.

Comment: Thanks for addressing all my questions, you've been very helpful indeed!